# How to call authentication once when the app is opened?

Tags: java, android

Biometric Authentication is called after navigating through different activities in the app. How do I call the authentication only once when the app is opened?

Comment: It's better if you provide some code snippets of the implementation you have. With the info you gave I can only say, it doesnt work if you place the said code on the lifecycle methods from the application class? (You would have to create your own class that extends from Application and call it on the manifest)

Comment: Do you want to authenticate biometric only when app starting and in single activity, or do you want to authenticate biometric in every activity?